# Is there any java library to access client's emails?

Tags: java, email

I am looking for a java library to access(show) client's emails in a web app.

For instance user comes to the site, enters credentials, smtp and all this stuff (like when doing Import in Thunderbird or Outlook) and our website can show him his emails in the browser...

Are you aware of such library? Is this possible?

IIRC, JavaMail is mostly for sending emails but what I need is to **access** and list client's emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there many opensource client mail tools which can be coustomised as you need, please check below below

[Client Emails Access](http://java-source.net/open-source/mail-clients)

***Update :*** 
check this [Chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java.asp)

Here is a sample code [how-to-create-an-e-mail-client-in-java](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-create-an-e-mail-client-in-java.html)

Comment: Yes, but most of them are outdated or no longer exists on their websites: eg Polarbar, Columba, IceMail...

Comment: Thanks, +1 for this library, seems it supports a lot of features: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/imap-features.asp. Now let's see if my customer wants to buy it:)

Answer (score 1):

Yes Javamail can do exactly what you are asking.  Javamail isn't for just sending emails.  You can access a user's mailbox.  Sending emails is over the SMTP protocol.  Javamail supports SMTP, POP3, and IMAP.  You're interested in POP3 or IMAP.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html